# horizontal scrolled view for tabwiget not slide tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabwidget

I am using horizontal scrolled view but the tabs not slide only content change. Please help me. When I flip the pages then tabs not flip.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

//

```
TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tw.getParent();
HorizontalScrollView hs = new HorizontalScrollView(getActivity());
hs.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.addView(hs, 0);
ll.removeView(tw);
hs.addView(tw);
hs.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
hs.setFillViewport(true);
```

when I flip the pages then tabs not flip.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70243/farsi-programming-discussion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TabHost I think.
At [This Link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.widget.TabHost) you can find more than 30 examples to use TabHost and TabWidget Look at the my sample layout and you should also change your code according to examples.
There is also good simple example : http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >
       <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
            .
            .
            .
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```